# Spark column string replace when present in other column (row)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I would like to remove strings from `col1` that are present in `col2`:

```
val df = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
("Hi I heard about Spark", "Spark"),
("I wish Java could use case classes", "Java"),
("Logistic regression models are neat", "models")
)).toDF("sentence", "label")
```

using `regexp_replace` or `translate` ref: [spark functions api](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$)

```
val res = df.withColumn("sentence_without_label", regexp_replace 
(col("sentence") , "(?????)", "" ))
```

so that `res` looks as below:

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could simply use `regexp_replace`

```
df5.withColumn("sentence_without_label", regexp_replace($"sentence" , lit($"label"), lit("" )))
```

or you can use simple udf function as below

```
val df5 = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
  ("Hi I heard about Spark", "Spark"),
  ("I wish Java could use case classes", "Java"),
  ("Logistic regression models are neat", "models")
)).toDF("sentence", "label")

val replace = udf((data: String , rep : String)=>data.replaceAll(rep, ""))

val res = df5.withColumn("sentence_without_label", replace($"sentence" , $"label"))

res.show()
```

Output:

```
+-----------------------------------+------+------------------------------+
|sentence                           |label |sentence_without_label        |
+-----------------------------------+------+------------------------------+
|Hi I heard about Spark             |Spark |Hi I heard about              |
|I wish Java could use case classes |Java  |I wish  could use case classes|
|Logistic regression models are neat|models|Logistic regression  are neat |
+-----------------------------------+------+------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 13):

If `label` it just a literal it is pretty simple:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

df.withColumn("sentence_without_label", 
  regexp_replace(col("sentence"), col("label"), lit(""))).show(false)

+-----------------------------------+------+------------------------------+
|sentence                           |label |sentence_without_label        |
+-----------------------------------+------+------------------------------+
|Hi I heard about Spark             |Spark |Hi I heard about              |
|I wish Java could use case classes |Java  |I wish  could use case classes|
|Logistic regression models are neat|models|Logistic regression  are neat |
+-----------------------------------+------+------------------------------+
```

In Spark 1.6 you can do the same with `expr`:

```
df.withColumn(
  "sentence_without_label",
  expr("regexp_replace(sentence, label, '')"))
```