# Scala Spark Replace empty String with NULL

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

What I want here is to replace a value in a specific column to null if it's empty String.

The reason is I am using `org.apache.spark.sql.functions.coalesce` to fill one of the Dataframe's column based on another columns, but I have noticed in some rows the value is `empty String` instead of `null` so the `coalesce` function doesn't work as expected.

```
val myCoalesceColumnorder: Seq[String] = Seq("xx", "yy", "zz"),

val resolvedDf = df.select(
   df("a"),
   df("b"),
   lower(org.apache.spark.sql.functions.coalesce(myCoalesceColumnorder.map(x => adjust(x)): _*)).as("resolved_id")
)
```

In the above example, I expected to first fill `resolved_id` with column  `xx` if it' not null and if it's null with column `yy` and so on. But since sometime column `xx` is filled with `""` instead of null I get `""` in 'resolved_id'.

I have tried to fix it with

```
resolvedDf.na.replace("resolved_id", Map("" -> null))
```

But based on the `na.replace` documentation it only works if both key and value are either `Bolean` or `String` or `Double` so I can not use `null` here.

I don't want to use **`UDF`** because of the performance issue, I just want to know is there any other trick to solve this issue?

One other way I can fix this is by using `when` but not sure about the performance

```
resolvedDf
      .withColumn("resolved_id", when(col("resolved_id").equalTo(""), null).otherwise(col("resolved_id")))
```

Comment: please look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45615621/spark-column-string-replace-when-present-in-other-column-row

Answer (score 2):

This is the right way with better performance
`resolvedDf.withColumn("resolved_id", when($"resolved_id" =!= "", $"resolved_id"))`

Basically no need to use `otherwise` method.

You can check sources::: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.scala#L507

```
/**
   * Evaluates a list of conditions and returns one of multiple possible result expressions.
   * If otherwise is not defined at the end, null is returned for unmatched conditions.
   *
   * {{{
   *   // Example: encoding gender string column into integer.
   *
   *   // Scala:
   *   people.select(when(people("gender") === "male", 0)
   *     .when(people("gender") === "female", 1)
   *     .otherwise(2))
   *
   *   // Java:
   *   people.select(when(col("gender").equalTo("male"), 0)
   *     .when(col("gender").equalTo("female"), 1)
   *     .otherwise(2))
   * }}}
   *
   * @group expr_ops
   * @since 1.4.0
   */
  def when(condition: Column, value: Any): Column = this.expr match {
    case CaseWhen(branches, None) =>
      withExpr { CaseWhen(branches :+ ((condition.expr, lit(value).expr))) }
    case CaseWhen(branches, Some(_)) =>
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(
        "when() cannot be applied once otherwise() is applied")
    case _ =>
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(
        "when() can only be applied on a Column previously generated by when() function")
  }
```

Comment: My point here is that, there is no performance issue with `when` clause. So you can use it

Comment: You can check again. Now you don't need to use `otherwise` method. :)

Comment: =!= for not equal