# Replace substring containing dollar sign ($) with other column value pyspark

Tags: regex, apache-spark, replace, pyspark

I am trying to replace the substring `'$NUMBER'` with the value in the column 'number' for each row. 
I tried

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.Types import StringType

replace_udf = udf(
    lambda long_text, number: long_text.replace("$NUMBER", number),
    StringType()
)

df = df.withColumn('long_text',replace_udf(col('long_text'),col('number')))
```

and

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

df = df.withColumn('long_text',expr("regexp_replace(long_text, '$NUMBER', number)"))
```

but nothing works. I can't figure out how another column can be the replacement for the substring.

SAMPLE:

```python
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("hahaha the $NUMBER is good",3),
        ("i dont know about $NUMBER",2),
        ("what is $NUMBER doing?",5),\
        ("ajajaj $NUMBER",2),
        ("$NUMBER dwarfs",1)
    ],
    ["long_text","number"]
)
```

INPUT:

```python
+---------------------------------+------+
|           long_text .           |number|
+---------------------------------+------+
|hahaha the $NUMBER is good       |     3|
|    what is $NUMBER doing?       |     5|
|          ajajaj $NUMBER         |     2|
+---------------------------------+------+
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```python
+--------------------+------+
|           long_text|number|
+--------------------+------+
|hahaha the 3 is good|     3|
|    what is 5 doing?|     5|
|          ajajaj 123|     2|
+--------------------+------+
```

Similar question where the answeres didn't cover the column replacement: 
[Spark column string replace when present in other column (row)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45615621/spark-column-string-replace-when-present-in-other-column-row)

Comment: Can you provide a sample input and expected output?

Comment: `$` is a special symbol in regex, which mean match at the end of the string. You need to escape it with a slash: `\$NUMBER`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `$` has a special meaning in regular expressions, which means match the end of the line. So your code:

```python
regexp_replace(long_text, '$NUMBER', number)
```

Is trying to match the pattern: end of line followed by the literal string `NUMBER` (which can never match anything).

In order to match a `$` (or any other regex special character), you have to escape it with a `\`.

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

df = df.withColumn('long_text',expr("regexp_replace(long_text, '\$NUMBER', number)"))
df.show()
#+--------------------+------+
#|           long_text|number|
#+--------------------+------+
#|hahaha the 3 is good|     3|
#|    what is 5 doing?|     5|
#|            ajajaj 2|     2|
#+--------------------+------+
```

Comment: I think you need to escape the backslash or make it a raw string.

Answer (score 1):

You have to cast the number column to string with str() before you can use with replace in your lambda:

```
from pyspark.sql import types as T
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

l = [(  'hahaha the $NUMBER is good',    3)
     ,('what is $NUMBER doing?'         ,   5)
     ,('ajajaj $NUMBER  '       ,  2)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(l,['long_text','number'])

#Just added str() to your function
replace_udf = F.udf(lambda long_text, number: long_text.replace("$NUMBER", str(number)), T.StringType())

df.withColumn('long_text',replace_udf(F.col('long_text'),F.col('number'))).show()

+--------------------+------+ 
|           long_text|number| 
+--------------------+------+ 
|hahaha the 3 is good|     3| 
|    what is 5 doing?|     5|
|           ajajaj 2 |     2| 
+--------------------+------+
```