# Pyspark replace string from column based on pattern from another column

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataframe with a text column and a name column. I would like to check if the name exists in the text column and if it does to replace it with some value.
I was hoping that the following would work:

```
df = df.withColumn("new_text",regex_replace(col("text),col("name"),"NAME"))
```

but Column is not iterable so it does not work. Do I have to write a udf to do that? How would that look like?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45615621/spark-column-string-replace-when-present-in-other-column-row

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a column value as a parameter to a spark DataFrame function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51140470/using-a-column-value-as-a-parameter-to-a-spark-dataframe-function)

Comment: @giser_yugang this is pyspark your linked question is about scala.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are almost close. Here is detailed example with `withColumn` and `selectExpr` options:

Sample df

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([('This is','This'),
('That is','That'),
('That is','There')],
['text','name'])

#+-------+-----+
#|   text| name|
#+-------+-----+
#|This is| This|
#|That is| That|
#|That is|There|
#+-------+-----+
```

**Option 1:** `withColumn` using `expr` function

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr, regexp_replace

df.withColumn("new_col1",expr("regexp_replace(text,name,'NAME')")).show()

#+-------+-----+--------+
#|   text| name|new_col1|
#+-------+-----+--------+
#|This is| This| NAME is|
#|That is| That| NAME is|
#|That is|There| That is|
#+-------+-----+--------+
```

**Option 2:** `selectExpr` using `regexp_replace`

```
 from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace


df.selectExpr("*",
          "regexp_replace(text,name,'NAME') AS new_text").show()

#+-------+-----+--------+
#|   text| name|new_text|
#+-------+-----+--------+
#|This is| This| NAME is|
#|That is| That| NAME is|
#|That is|There| That is|
#+-------+-----+--------+
```

Comment: Do you happen to know how to handle the case when name is a regex expression? I'm seeing an issue with expr("regexp_replace(column, 'regex',  'replace_value')")

Comment: To add, it's because the 'regex' is regex, but it being surrounded as a string from expr seems to interfere.

Comment: I think I solved it, but not sure why. ^([^.]+)?\\. worked instead of ^.*?\\. (but the latter works when I don't use expr)