# How to specify a different column for the second argument of the regexp_replace function?

Tags: pyspark, substring, databricks, regexp-replace

I tried to replace part of the column text with "?". But I got an error.
I'd like to use the native dataframe in spark.

TypeError: Column is not iterable

```
data = [("John Doe", "123 Main St, Anytown, USA"),
        ("Jane Smith", "456 High St, Somewhere, USA")]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["name", "address"])
```

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace, col
start = 3
end = 10
df_masked = df.withColumn("address_masked", regexp_replace(col("address"), substring("address", start, end), "??????????"))
```

expected result

| name | address_masked |
| --- | --- |
| John Doe | 123????????, Anytown, USA |
| Jane Smith | 456??????????, Somewhere, USA |

Comment: Possible duplicate of - [Pyspark replace string from column based on pattern from another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56371701/pyspark-replace-string-from-column-based-on-pattern-from-another-column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `expr()` to iterate through the column using `substring` function

**`Example:`**

```
df_masked = df.withColumn("address_masked", expr(f'regexp_replace(address, substring(address, {start}, {end}), "??????????")'))
#name   address address_masked
#John Doe   123 Main St, Anytown, USA   12?????????? Anytown, USA
#Jane Smith 456 High St, Somewhere, USA 45?????????? Somewhere, USA
```